# rmarkdown ggplot tufte theme background color

Tags: r, ggplot2, r-markdown

In the `Rmarkdown` with tufte theme, when I use `ggplot2`, I see that background is white and does not blend with background color of html file. See below. using transparent in `ggplot2` does not help.

Is there a way to make background of `ggplot2` blend with background of html file in `Rmarkdow` with tufte theme. See below

[image]

Comment: I wonder if package **thematic** could help? I saw one of the examples was based on a tufte handout theme in the [R Markdown section of the auto theming article](https://rstudio.github.io/thematic/articles/auto.html#r-markdown)

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same problem. This is a two-step solution:

1. The background of your `ggplot()` needs to be transparent. Set the `plot.background = element_blank()` and `panel.background = element_blank()` inside the `theme()` function.
2. The most important aspect is the argument `bg = transparent` in the code chunk :

```
{r dev.args = list(bg = 'transparent')}

data %>%
 ggplot() +
 geom_line() +
 theme(
  plot.background = element_blank(),
  panel.background = element_blank()
  )
```

Comment: Thank you, let me give it a try next time.

Answer (score 0):

I did not find a way to set the background of the ggplot to 100% transparance or NULL. But you can define the `plot.background` and `legend.background` in the `theme` of the ggplot objects so that it is compatible with the style of the knit'ed html. For instance in this ggplot, resulting in [this render](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ahR5Y.png):

````
```{r fig-margin, fig.margin = TRUE, fig.cap = "MPG vs horsepower, colored by transmission.", fig.width=3.5, fig.height=3.5, cache=TRUE, message=FALSE}
library(ggplot2)
mtcars2 <- mtcars
mtcars2$am <- factor(
  mtcars$am, labels = c('automatic', 'manual')
)
ggplot(mtcars2, aes(hp, mpg, color = am)) +
  geom_point() + geom_smooth() +
  theme(legend.position = 'bottom',
        plot.background = element_rect(fill = "#fffff8"),
        legend.background = element_rect(fill = "#fffff8"))
```
````

I took the .Rmd code from [here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/rstudio/tufte/master/inst/rmarkdown/templates/tufte_html/skeleton/skeleton.Rmd)